# Generate paypal payment links with amout and recipient

Tags: php, paypal

I need to dinamically generate PayPal links with customized payment amounts and recipients. I don't know much about PayPal's way of handling this kind of stuff, and I actually wonder whether it is possible. I have a table with user's email address and payment value and, on the last column, I need to put that link that, clicked, takes to the PayPal's page where, after security checks and everything, the amount of money by me given can be directly transferred to the email address of the user.

Is it possible to do something like this? I'm working in PHP.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

please, read documentation - it's all very well described. you will need to register at https://developer.paypal.com/; refer to https://www.paypal.com/documentation for more information.

I believe paypal standard payments would suffice your needs. read this https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_WebsitePaymentsStandard_IntegrationGuide.pdf -- it has all sorts of samples.

---

when we integrate paypal, we usually do like this: user picks goods to purchase, then proceeds to checkout. at this point, form is created as per documentation, and that form includes merchant account to use for processing the payment. in the form you also specify: notify_url and cancel_url, so you would get notification from the paypal as to what happened and to which account. that should address your needs.

sample form:

```
<form action="https://www.'.$this->isSandbox().'paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="'.$this->api->getConfig('billing/paypal/merchant').'">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="'.addslashes($_GET['descr']).'"> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="'.addslashes($_GET['id']).'"> 
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="'.addslashes($_GET['amount']).'">
<input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$this->api->getDestinationURL('/ppproxy',array('ipn'=>$_GET['id'])).'">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$this->api->getDestinationURL('/ppproxy',array('cancel'=>$_GET['id'])).'">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$this->api->getDestinationURL('/ppproxy',array('success'=>$_GET['id'])).'">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="'.addslashes($_GET['currency']).'"> 
</form>
```

sample callback handler:

....

```
if($_POST){
    // might be getting adta from paypal! better log!
    foreach ($_POST as $key=>$value) $postdata.=$key."=".urlencode($value)."&";
    $postdata.="cmd=_notify-validate";
    $curl = curl_init("https://www.".$this->isSandbox()."paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr");
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 1);
    $response = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
    $this->api->logger->logLine($response);
    if ($response != "VERIFIED"){
        $this->api->logger->logLine('FAILED: post='.print_r($_POST,true));
        exit;
    }else{
        $this->api->logger->logLine('VERIFIED: post='.print_r($_POST,true));
    }
    if($_POST['payment_status']=='Completed' and $_POST['txn_type']!='reversal')return true; // or perform your desired actions

    exit;
}
```

excerpt from agiletoolkit.org paypal billing addon

Comment: In what way am I able to define the email address pf the recipient that, thus, isn't mine? I've gone through the the pdf you linked but haven't really understood how I can do that...

Comment: Ste_95: Look at Mass Pay and the MassPay API.
You'll need to contact Customer Service to get the MassPay API enabled on your account, but that shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Actually, that is going to be an issue. This question is for a project that's going to be public, thus I don't know the addresses of the administrators that will use it.

This is my idea: the admin gives his paypal address as money source, and, with it (maybe with some verification first), I provide him dynamic links to custom recipients and with custom amounts. Hope is clear...

Comment: I agree with Robert. Look at the MassPay APIs as this, and Adaptive Payments Simple Pay API calls are the only methods you will be able to use to send funds via API. Also, Robert was referring to the ability to enable MassPay on your account not being an issue, not your ability to interpret the documentation.

If you want assistance with this, you will need to better describe your delima because it should be very simple to create a database full of emails and amounts and build a massPay file / API call.

Comment: Ok, I think MassPay is the right thing to use even if I only have one e-mail address. Anyway, I'll read thoroughly the documentation here and maybe post here the final code I'll have:
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_MassPayOverview

Thanks.